# Counter-examples of Galois Correspondence

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

What are some examples of a separable field extension $L/K$ and a subgroup $H$ of $\text{Aut}(L/K)$ such that $\text{Aut}(L/L^H) \neq H$? Here $L^H$ means the fixed field of $H$.

Comment: Let $K=\Bbb{F}_p$, $L$ its algebraic closure, and $H$ the group generated by the Frobenius automorphism. The recurring theme in infinite Galois theory is that $H$ and its closure (w.r.t. Krull topology) share the same fixed field. Here $L^H=K$, but $Aut(L/K)$ is much larger.

Answer (score 2):

For $H$ finite, it is impossible:

Dummit & Foote Section 14.2 Corollary 11 (adapted with your notation):

Let $H$ be a finite subgroup of automorphisms of a field $L$ and $L^{H}$ be the fixed field, then $Aut(L/L^{H})=H$.

In your problem, $H\leq Aut(L/K)\leq Aut(L)$, we don't care about $K$ at all, we still get $Aut(L/L^{H})=H$.

Comment: Presumably the point is to find an example where $H$ is infinite.

Comment: @Slade Thanks. I have zero knowledge on infinite Galois theory. I edited the post to emphasize this is the finite case.